# Constructing a contraction

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, contraction-operator

Let $(X,d)$ be a complete metric space and $f_i$ are contractions on $X$ with contractivity factors $s_i$. Suppose $s_i$ are eventually decreasing. Then we get $s_i$ converges in $[0,1)$, to say $s$. I am trying to construct a contraction on $X$ with contractivity factor $s$. I tried to check whether $(f_i(x))_{i\ge1}$ is cauchy for given $x\in X$. But I am stuck there. Please give me a direction.

Comment: Well, if $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $f_n(x)=\frac{x}{n}+n,$ then $f_n$ fits into your set-up but $f_n(x)$ diverges for every $x$, so you need something else.

Comment: On the other hand I think that if $f_n$ is pointwise convergent then $\lim f_n$ is a contraction with factor $\lim s_n$. I also assume that by "contractivity factor" you mean any factor, not [the Lipschitz constant of $f$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_mapping)?

Comment: I meant the Lipschitz constant<1 as contractivity factor.